# Load balancing in home network

Tags: networking

I am trying to balance the network usage at home. For this I want to have three users, which can use the full bandwidth but are allowed to use a minimum bandwith at all time.

For example: 1 Gbit/s = full bandwith, 200Mbit/s = minimum bandwith

User 1: Tries to get 1Gbit/s and gets 700Mbits/s

User 2: Tries to get 200MBit/s and gets 200MBit/s

User 3: Tries to get 100MBit/s and gets 100MBit/s

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: you can't set a minimum bandwidth, because that means one could not download unless they exceed the minimum treshold. Do you mean limited bandwidth instead?

Comment: The minimum bandwith should be the bandwith that a user can get at all time regardless of what the other users are doing. This is in my example 200Mbit/s. If only one user is currently active, he should get the full bandwidth (1Gbit/s in my example).

Comment: Most of the time people feel the need to do this, it's because their router has bad queue management (bufferbloat), and the only fix needed is to run a Smart Queue Management (SQM) algorithm such as Cake or FQ-CoDel on the router.

Comment: You have provided insufficient information.  What router?  Does a user = an IP? Upload or download limit?

Comment: A different queue management does not fulfill my requirements, since I need the minimum bandwith regardless of what data has been requested.

I do not have any router yet, since this should be a new part of my home network. A user either needs to have a Range of IPs, a Subnet, a own VLAN or something similar. I need both upload and download.

Comment: Implement QOS on the network. You can use pfsense/opensense, or dd-wrt/openwrt. There are commercially available devices that can also use these features, but are sold as business grade, and are usually too expensive for home users to consider. The pfsense option is good for a diy box, openwrt and ddwrt are good for off the shelf solutions, and usually much cheaper than the other two options.